# Bad Request when trying to get an access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, nest-device-access

I'm trying to use the Nest Device API, however I am unable to get an Access Token as it throws

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I've downloaded my credentials.json from GCP and I open a new tab with the AUTH_URL below:

```js
    const credentials = require('../../../credentials.json');
    
    const PROJECT_ID = <NEST DEVICE API PROJECT ID>;
    const REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/connect/callback';
    const AUTH_URL =
      `https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections/${PROJECT_ID}/auth?` +
      `redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URL}&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&client_id=${credentials.web.client_id}&` +
      `response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service`;
```

From that, I have my callback page that gets the authcode.

```js
const credentials = require('../../../credentials.json');
const { code } = router.query; // Auth Code

try {
  const url =
    `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id=${credentials.web.client_id}` +
    `&client_secret=${credentials.web.client_secret}&code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code&` +
    `redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URL}`;

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    });
    console.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
 console.error(e);
}
```

This is where the API returns the above error.  I have also tried taking this URL and doing `curl -L -X POST <url>` however I get exactly the same results.

Any ideas?

Comment: if your method is `POST` shouldn't you have a request body? and is that second codeblock in a browser? or are you using node-fetch library for some reason?

Comment: I haven't actually changed anything in the code above and it now works.  No idea what I changed elsewhere that would make it work either :/

Comment: Good to hear that its working now. Please do let us know if you have any issues. Just  for future reference. https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#get_an_access_token